# How to get how many files in folders and subfolders in a directory with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know how many files in the folders and their subfolders. I search here and some google pages but I didn't find what I'm looking for. The closest thing I've been looking for is this.

```
    Sub MainList()
    'Updateby Extendoffice
    Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)
    Call ListFilesInFolder(xDir, True)
    End Sub

    Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal xFolderName As String, ByVal xIsSubfolders As Boolean)
    Dim xFileSystemObject As Object
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xSubFolder As Object
    Dim xFile As Object
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Set xFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFolder = xFileSystemObject.GetFolder(xFolderName)
    rowIndex = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
      Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Formula = xFile.Name
      rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    Next xFile
    If xIsSubfolders Then
      For Each xSubFolder In xFolder.SubFolders
        ListFilesInFolder xSubFolder.Path, True
      Next xSubFolder
    End If
    Set xFile = Nothing
    Set xFolder = Nothing
    Set xFileSystemObject = Nothing
    End Sub

    Function GetFileOwner(ByVal xPath As String, ByVal xName As String)
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xFolderItem As Object
    Dim xShell As Object
    xName = StrConv(xName, vbUnicode)
    xPath = StrConv(xPath, vbUnicode)
    Set xShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set xFolder = xShell.Namespace(StrConv(xPath, vbFromUnicode))
    If Not xFolder Is Nothing Then
      Set xFolderItem = xFolder.ParseName(StrConv(xName, vbFromUnicode))
    End If
    If Not xFolderItem Is Nothing Then
      GetFileOwner = xFolder.GetDetailsOf(xFolderItem, 8)
    Else
      GetFileOwner = ""
    End If
    Set xShell = Nothing
    Set xFolder = Nothing
    Set xFolderItem = Nothing
    End Function
```

But it gives me the files list. I want to know how many file is there each folder? Do you have a any suggestion?

**EDİT:**

```
-MainFolder
  -- SubFolder1 -- Has .. file
  -- SubFolder2 -- Has .. file
     --SubFolder2 subfolder -- Has .. file
     --SubFolder2 subfolder1 -- Has .. file
     --SubFolder2 subfolder2 -- Has .. file
  -- SubFolder3 -- Has .. file
.
.
.
```

I want to something like this structure in excel worksheet.

Comment: So, your code returns what you need and you only want that at the end to send a message containing the total (**processed**) files in the processed folder (including subfolders). Is this a correct understanding? Or you need a separate code to only return the above mentioned number of **existing** files? To know that prior to their processing...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, exactly. I don't want to know files names. I need only this information, how many files in  each folder and their subfolders in a directory.

Comment: But you did not exactly answer my question... Is it about adapting the existing code to (also) return the number of processed files, or you wont knowing the number before using the existing code?

Comment: @FaneDuru I don't know the number before using the existing code, it changes directory to directory?

Comment: Your answer is not so clear/direct, but I will take it that you need to adapt the existing solution, in order to return the number of **processed files** in the chosen folder (including subfolders)...